# if/elseif not working right

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have a script that checks how much memory the top w3wp process is using.  Then depending on how close to 1 gig it is using, it will give out a message.

```
param($warn, $crit)
$LastExitCode = 3
$Output1 = ""
$output = ""
$myW3WP = Get-Process w3wp | Sort -Descending WS | select -first 1 |
          Measure-Object WS -Sum 
$myW3WP = ("{0:N2} " -f ($myW3WP.sum / 1mb))
$myW3WP.trim()
if ($myW3WP -gt $crit) {
    $LastExitCode = 2
    $output1 = "CRITICAL: Memory for W3WP has passed 1 gig $myW3WP"
    $output = $output1
} elseif ($myW3WP -gt $warn) {
    $LastExitCode = 1
    $output1 = "WARN: Memory for W3WP is getting close to 1 gig $myW3WP"
    $output = $output1
} else {
    $LastExitCode = 0
}

$output = $output1
Write-Host $output $LastExitCode "$myW3WP >= " $crit  ($myW3WP -gt $crit) "$myW3WP >= " $warn ($myW3WP -gt $warn)
$myW3WP = ""
```

In values for `$crit` is 1000 and the value for `$warn` is 900.
(Note: the `Write-Host` line is like that for troubleshooting)

Here is the output I am getting:

> CRITICAL: Memory for W3WP has passed 1 gig 161.03  2 161.03  >=  1000 True 161.03  >=  900 False

The 161.03 is the megs of RAM being used.

Any ideas on why it is saying 161.03 is greater than 1000?

Comment: Because you changed the value of `$myW3WP` from numerical into a string with the `-f` operator. Now, since `$myW3WP` is a string, a string comparison is performed and *alphabetically* `161` is greater than `1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't compare apples and oranges!

You'll need a numerical value if you want to compare it to other numerical values

When you call:

```
$myW3WP = ("{0:N2} " -f ($myW3WP.sum / 1mb))
$myW3WP.trim()
```

you create a *string*.

Replace those two lines with just:

```
$myW3WP = $myW3WP.Sum / 1MB
```

And it'll work

Comment: Perfect....I had a feeling a string was getting in there somehow.  I did that change, removed the trim line, and now my output looks like:  222.63671875 >=  1000 False 222.63671875 >=  900 False

Comment: Glad it helped. Btw `-gt` is equivalent to `>` - you need to use `-ge` if you want a `>=` comparison

Answer (score 1):

`$myW3WP` is a string, not a number, so you're doing a textual comparison, rather than a numeric one. The line:

```
$myW3WP = ("{0:N2} " -f ($myW3WP.sum / 1mb))
```

Is what forces the variable to be a string. Just leave it as a number and don't worry about the decimal places:

```
$myW3WP = $myW3WP.sum / 1mb
```

Comment: Perfect....I had a feeling a string was getting in there somehow.  I did that change, removed the trim line, and now my output looks like:  222.63671875 >=  1000 False 222.63671875 >=  900 False